# How to get device name for a mount in python

Tags: python, smb

On my mac I've mapped an SMB share as a Volume. I would like to get the real path of this Volume in my python code.

```
➜  MYVOLUME pwd
/Volumes/MYVOLUME
➜  MYVOLUME mount
/dev/disk1s1 on / (apfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s4 on /private/var/vm (apfs, local, noexec, journaled, noatime, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
//fistname.lastname@10.10.50.20/Projects/SomeProject on /Volumes/MYVOLUME (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by user)
```

I would like to get the `//fistname.lastname@10.10.50.20/Projects/SomeProject` part. I've tried using below but it doesn't get me the actual SMB location I want.

```
def find_mount_point(self,path):
    path = os.path.abspath(path)
    while not os.path.ismount(path):
        path = os.path.dirname(path)
    return path
```

Comment: That’s not a `path` at all, but a *device* name.

Comment: The first part of the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453602/how-to-find-the-mountpoint-a-file-resides-on plus the comment of @DavisHerring plus 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112492/iterating-through-mount-points-using-python should give you the answer.

Comment: @NPE Great. That worked! `psutil.disk_partitions(all=True)` did the trick. If you want to replace your comment by an answer, I'd be happy to accept.

Comment: World you bé offended if I flag this answer as a duplicate then ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating through mount points using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112492/iterating-through-mount-points-using-python)

Comment: It seems it is not a duplicate so I posted an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `psutil` library

Working example

```
def find_sdiskpart(path):
    path = os.path.abspath(path)
    while not os.path.ismount(path):
        path = os.path.dirname(path)
    p = [p for p in psutil.disk_partitions(all=True) if p.mountpoint == path.__str__()]
    l = len(p)
    if len(p) == 1:
        print type(p[0])
        return p[0]
    raise psutil.Error
```

The function will return a `<class 'psutil._common.sdiskpart'>`containg mountpoint and device name

Can be used like this

```
try:
    p = find_sdiskpart(".")
    print p.mountpoint
    print p.device
except psutil.Error:
    print 'strange'
```